# assigning value to member of struct via pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I',m probably doing some incredibly stupid mistake, but i cannot find it, it is simple that:

```
int main()
{

typedef struct drzemka typ;
struct drzemka {     
int strukcje;
};
typ *d;
d->strukcje = 1;
}
```

and it is not working

Comment: **Read the warnings emitted by your compiler**. It should be saying something about the use of uninitialized variable `d`.

Comment: gcc doesn't give an error on compilation.

Comment: @BSull: Try turning on some reasonable warning settings like `-Wall`, and you'll plainly see "warning: ‘d’ is used uninitialized in this function".

Comment: Yeah, I'm just saying it's not a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now your pointer is not set to a valid piece of memory.  You need to allocated this memory for the `struct`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* ... */
typ *d = malloc(sizeof(typ));
```

As with any memory you allocate, remember to free it after you're done:

```
free(d);
```

Comment: I still wonder why having the struct inside the main() scope is good in any way

Comment: @Yarneo: It's not good.  It's not standard C, although GCC allows it as an extension.  The struct should be defined outside of `main`.

Comment: Cheers for the quick response @AdamRosenfield

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `d` to something valid. You have to give it some memory. Right now it's a pointer of type `typ` that's pointing to nothing. Then you're trying to deference the nothing.

Either assign some memory from the heap to your pointer and use it as you are:

```
typ *d = malloc(sizeof(typ)); 
d->strukcje = 1;
free(d);
```

Or put a static copy on the stack:

```
typ d;
d.strukcje = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be:

```
struct drzemka {     
int strukcje;
};
typedef struct drzemka typ;


int main()
{
   typ d;
   d.strukcje = 1;
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
 typ* d = (typ *) malloc(sizeof(typ));
 d->strukcje = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
typedef struct drzemka {     
    int strukcje;
}typ;

int main() {
    typ d;
    typ * p = &d;
    p->strukcje = 1;
    printf("The value of strukcje is %d",p->strukcje);
}
```